# how subtitle (.scc) text position is dynamic in video, even the styling is not in decoded file?

Tags: decode, styling, subtitle

Some time caption comes at top of the screen and some time at the bottom, and when we decode the file using some decoder, it will not return styling CSS, on the file?

Answer (score 0):

SCC is not an encoded format, its indifferent format, we can't ready by decoding. It's required programming to convert to a readable format, So we can say that its specific to different users.

Even if u decode using some decoder you maybe not get the expected result.

The format of the SCC file is usually :

03:00:00;12 942c 9429 94d0 9723 c461 6ee9 e5ec 2054 e967 e5f2 ba20 c8e9 2c20 cee5 e967 6862 eff2 a180 9470 9723 54ef 6461 7920 73ef 6de5 f468 e96e 6720 54e9 67e5 f2f4 6173 f4e9 e380

03:00:05;27 9420 94ae 9152 97a1 e973 2068 6170 70e5 6ee9 6e67 2061 f420 73e3 68ef efec a180 91f2 97a1 49f4 a773 20f4 68e5 20d3 70f2 e96e 6720 d3e9 6e67 a180 942f